# Highlight weekends in a Crosstab Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, highlight, crosstab

I'm using Crystal Reports 14, and i have a crosstab report, which i have the days of the month as columns. I have a field from the db, which calculates which days are Saturdays and Sundays. Depending on the value of this field i want to highlight the whole column.